# Use a select option as a class on another element

Tags: jquery, html-select

I'm looking to pass the select option value as a class on another field.

I've managed to work this manually but would like it to word dynamically so finds the actual option selected and uses that value as a class.
See link:
https://jsfiddle.net/tmtgxL0n/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".value").find('#pa_mount-colour').change(function() {
    var jQueryval = jQuery(this).val();

    if(jQueryval === 'cream'){
        jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery__image').addClass("cream");
    }else{
        jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery__image').removeClass("cream");
    }
});
```

});

Just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: `.addClass(jQueryval)` ?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: `I've managed to work this manually`->please explain it?

Comment: I want the class to automatically pull from the option value. If it can look up the option selected and add the class from the option value.

if(jQueryval === '*selectvalue'){
        jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery__image').addClass("*selectvalue");
    }else{
        jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery__image').removeClass("*selectvalue");
    }

Comment: K why dont you directly add that value to the element, check my answer

Comment: @DB86  only for one select-option or for all select-option from different select-boxes?

Comment: I have edited my answer which meets exactly your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You're already dynamically getting the selected value:

```
var jQueryval = jQuery(this).val();
```

Simply use that:

```
jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery__image').toggleClass(jQueryval);
```

Note the use of `toggleClass()` which will automatically check if the target element has a class already and add or remove that class accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the value of select to be the class of another, try this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
  {
   function removeExistingClass()
   {
    jQuery('.value #pa_mount-colour option').each(function(){
     jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery__image').removeClass($(this).val());
    });
   }

   jQuery('.value #pa_mount-colour').change(function() 
   {
       var jQueryval = jQuery(this).val();
       removeExistingClass();
       // this will remove if any prevous class added from the selects value
       jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery__image').addClass(jQueryval);

   });
  });
```

```css
.red{border:6px red solid;}    
.green{border:6px green solid;}
.blue{border:6px blue solid;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="value">
   <select id="pa_mount-colour">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
   </select>
   </div>

   <div class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image">Select will change my class</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    function removeExistingClass(){
        $('#pa_mount-colour option').each(function(){
            $('.listings-sidebar-content').removeClass($(this).val());
        });
    }

    $('#pa_mount-colour').change(function() {
        var jQueryval = $(this).val();
        removeExistingClass();
        jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery__image').toggleClass(jQueryval);
    });

});
```